# Monaco font not appearing in PuTTY font list

Tags: windows-xp, putty, fonts

I'm using PuTTY 0.60 under Windows XP. I recently downloaded and installed the Monaco font, and configured PuTTY to use it. However, after reboot, the Monaco font doesn't appears in PuTTYs font list; it does appear installed, and other applications can use it.

At first I thought it was a problem of the file being encrypted (I had originally downloaded to an encrypted folder) so I decrypted it. After that, I noticed in file properties dialog that the file was "locked" due to having being downloaded form the net; I unlocked it pressing the button that says so. After a couple of reboots, I still cannot see the font in PuTTY's font selecion dialog; however, the sessions that I configured after installing the font still use it. I just cannot configure new sessions to use it.

Any ideas on how to make this font appears again in PuTTY's font selection dialog? Or any hint of why it doesn't appear there?

**Edit:** It appears that there are two versions of this font around. The one that I installed is supposed to be the latest version; however, it seems that its flags are incorrect. Since I updated this font after having installed the supposedly "old" version I guess I still can use it under PuTTY.

Guess PuTTY is picky regarding what is considered "fixed" compared with other programs.

Comment: Is the version of the font shown when you open the font file for viewing? What version is it?

Comment: IMHO this question can also be relevant to issues with the CMD font list, so perhaps an edit is in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [PuTTY manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-appearance), it will only allow you to select a fixed-width font.  My guess is the Monaco is not being listed as a fixed-width font, and therefore does not show up in the list of available fonts.

Comment: It does appear to be a fixed-width font.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_(typeface)

Comment: I would guess that the Monaco font does not have the correct "fixed pitch" attribute set on it to tell the system it is fixed width.  I've noticed on my system there are several fonts that should be fixed width that do not show up in that dialog.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the obvious font installation and registry changes, [Microsoft's KB 247185](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247815) teaches the criteria that must be observed in order for a font to be available in the Command Prompt, partially quoted below:

> **The fonts must meet the following criteria to be available in a command session window:**
>
> - The font must be a fixed-pitch font.
> - The font cannot be an italic
>   font.
> - The font cannot have a negative A or C space.
> - If it is a
>   TrueType font, it must be FF_MODERN.
> - If it is not a TrueType font, it
>   must be OEM_CHARSET.
>
> **Additional criteria for Asian installations:**
>
> - If it is not a TrueType font, the face name must be "Terminal."
> - If it is an Asian TrueType font, it must also be an Asian character set.

My understanding is that there's some overlap between these rules and those in PuTTY, particularly as pertains to TrueType requirements.

So by trial and error I've learned that there are multiple versions of the Monaco font available, and only some of these will work in CMD. An example of a correct version (2.0, to be precise) [is the one available on this link](http://www.gringod.com/wp-upload/MONACO.TTF) provided by [a SitePoint post on the so-called 'Top 10 Programming Fonts'](http://www.sitepoint.com/top-10-programming-fonts/).

Comment: Link not working, and there is no link to download from SitePoint post

Comment: @Rualark the link still works for me as of June 18, 2023

Answer (score 0):

Setting the font face to one not found in configuration dialog drop-down list can be done by manually editing the setting in it's storage (registry for original PuTTY, or text file for modern forks like KiTTY).

While not a comfortable way, you get what is otherwise impossible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).